# Expected Value Question - SMT 2020

Tags: expected-value

> If $a$ is picked randomly in the range $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})$ and $b$ is chosen such that
> $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1,$$ compute the expected value of $(b − a)$.

[image]

[image]

https://www.stanfordmathtournament.com/pdfs/smt2020/team-solutions.pdf

I have soved it differently given as an answer.

let me know if there is any flaw in deriving like you see in my answer.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained so that it does not rely on web-sources.

Comment: Shall I add an image of the solution

Comment: Yes you can add a picture but then its fine if you let the Link in for the reference. If its ever taken down there is still your picture.

Comment: Also your ,,solution" should be part of the question because all the answers here are not for the problem but for your question.

Comment: I chose to answer my question by checking the box ( answer your own question), a choice that is given to the question poser!

Comment: Yes but your question is about wether your solution is right not about solving the problem!

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it differently.

$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1$

$[\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}] = 1$

$b = \frac{a}{1-a}$

pdf of a => is 2

pdf of b is derived as below using CDF method:

$P_B(B\leq b) => P(\frac{a}{1-a}\leq b)$

$P(a \leq \frac{b}{1+b})$

$ =\frac{\frac{b}{1+b}-\frac{1}{4}}{{\frac{3}{4}} - \frac{1}{4}}$

$P(B\leq b)=2\frac{b}{1+b} - \frac{1}{2}$

Now differentiate to get the pdf

interval for b transforms to $(\frac{1}{3}, 3)$

Thus $P(B=b) = \frac{2}{(1+b)^2}$

$E(B) = \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{2b}{(1+b)^2}$

Put $u = (1+b)$ => $db = du$ and $b = u-1$

Now $E(b) = 2 \int_{\frac{4}{3}}^{4} (\frac{(u-1)}{u^2}du$

$E(b) = 2 \int_{\frac{4}{3}}^{4} \frac{1}{u}du - 2 \int_{\frac{4}{3}}^{4}\frac{1}{u^2}du$

$E(b) = 2\ln(3) - 1$

$ = \ln(9) - 1$

$E(a) = \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Thus $E(b - a) = E(b) - E(a)$

$E(b-a) = \ln(9) - 1 - \frac{1}{2}$

$E(b-a) = \ln(9) - \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Use \ln and \leq or \geq instead of <= or =>

Comment: sure, will edit the answer accordingly